# Android Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) onTokenRefresh() never called and getToken() returning null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I realize this question was raised before, but I have checked a substantial list of previous solutions and my problems mentioned in the subject remain.

Here's what I have:

1. MyFirebaseInstanceIDService class is almost straight out of the book:

   ```
   import android.util.Log;

   import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
   import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
   import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
   import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
   import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
   import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService;

   public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

   private static final String TAG = "MT: FIIDService";

   @Override
   public void onTokenRefresh() {
       // Get updated InstanceID token.
       String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
       Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
       sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
   }

   private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
       FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
       FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
       if (user != null) {
           FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
           DatabaseReference IDTokensRef = database.getReference(getString(R.string.firebase_idtokens));
           IDTokensRef.child(user.getUid()).setValue(token);
           Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token assigned to user: " + user.getDisplayName());
       }
   }
   ```
2. The service declared in the manifest (within the application clause), copied from the Firebase pages. Also, I have no "tools:node="merge" in the manifest, which solved the issue for some other people.

   ```
   <service
       android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
       </intent-filter>
   </service>
   ```
3. All the latest dependencies in the app level build.gradle:

   ```
   dependencies {
       implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta4'

       implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'

       implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
       implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
       implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
       implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2'
       implementation 'com.android.support:palette-v7:27.0.2'

       implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
       implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
       implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
       implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
       implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
       implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:1.0.1'
       implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
   }

   apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
   ```
4. The latest google services defined in the project level `build.gradle`:

   ```
   buildscript {
       repositories {
           jcenter()
           google()
       }
       dependencies {
           classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
           classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'  // Added when setting up Firebase
       }
   }

   allprojects {
       repositories {
           jcenter()
           google()
           maven {
               url "https://maven.google.com"
               name 'Google'
           }
       }
   }
   ```
5. To be sure, I have downloaded the `google-services.json` once again to the app folder, without any effect. Finally, I declare INTERNET and `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` permissions in the manifest.

I have had a similar app working in the past, so I know my setup should work. But somehow, even after uninstalling/reinstalling the app, both in the emulator (tried several types and API 25 & 26 versions) as well as on a real device, `onTokenRefresh` in the InstanceIDService is never called, and `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()` returns null, in any relevant class of my application.

It also does not seem to be a timing issue related to obtaining a token: I receive null both immediately after user signs on, and still, do just before signing off.

My basic question is: are there ways to debug/investigate the token problem? In logcat I do not see any indications that there is a Firebase problem.

Comment: This may not be the cause of the problem, but you should be using `firebase-ui-storage:3.1.2` with SDK version 11.8.0.  See the docs for [table of compatible versions](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#compatibility-with-firebase--google-play-services-libraries).

Comment: Check your logcat for `W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date`.  You may need to update Google Play services to get the latest version for compatibility with SDK 11.8.0

Comment: Thanks, I will try the update later, as it will also involve updating the glide version and will require code changes. Indeed, it's unlikely that it has anything to do with the token problem. I checked for the GooglePlayServices message, but it's not there. I think 3.1.1 is the latest.

Comment: FYI: If you have `google()` as a repository, you don't need to add `https://maven.google.com`. They're the same thing.

Comment: Thx, commented that out, without any effect on functionality. I need to read about those repositories. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out that occurrence of the problem depends on the firebase SDK version that is specified in the app level `build.gradle`: `onTokenRefresh` is no longer called as of SDK version 11.6.0. Looking at the release notes, this version has the following change related to token generation:

"Improved FCM token fetch logic so that the FCM token is now created faster and with less battery drain."

I assume that the FCM related changes in this release are related to my problem, and will issue a bug report.

**Update**: Firebase Support investigated the problem and reported back that the origin of the problem was the following lines in my AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"
    tools:node="remove"/>
```

which I once added to avoid requesting "prevent phone from sleeping permission". Without these lines in the manifest the FCM token is refreshed without issues in combination with SDK 11.8.0.

Comment: FWIW:  I have an app built with 11.8.0 and see `onTokenRefresh()` called for appropriate events, for example, when app data is cleared.  Don't know what is different about your configuration that causes it to fail.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure an official release will work in almost all cases. Anyway, I've reported a bug and hope they will be able to found out what's the matter. At the moment this is preventing me from updating to more recent versions.